# How do i manipulate array key and sort the key again?

Tags: php, arrays

hello guys i have a problem, i'm new programmer with lack of basic with array object manipulation

i have a case that i need to delete data in array but i need to rearrange the key based on the numbering like 1,2,3 if i delete the 2 the number 3 should be number 2.

```
$user_list = [
"user_1" => ["user_id" => 1234],
"user_2" => ["user_id" => 1324],
"user_3" => ["user_id" => 3321]
];
```

if i delete the number2 the data should be like this

```
$user_list = [
"user_1" => ["user_id" => 1234],
"user_2" => ["user_id" => 3321]
];
```

i already code like this

```
$user_list = [
"user_1" => ["user_id" => 1234],
"user_2" => ["user_id" => 1324],
"user_3" => ["user_id" => 3321]
];

foreach($user_list as $key => $value){
if($value["user_id"] == $user_id){
unset($key);
}
}
```

how do i rearrange it?, i try to learn deep enough but i'm stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, I think you would like to remove the value but not the key of the particular element. Instead you would like to replace the value of the particular key by the value of the next key of the associative array and so on and so forth and finally remove the last key of the associative array.
From this I have derived the following solution:

```
$arr1 = $user_list = [
"user_1" => "1234",
"user_2" => "1324",
"user_3" => "3321"
];
$keys = array_keys($arr1);

$searchKey = "user_2";
$startIndex = array_search($searchKey, $keys);
for($i = $startIndex; $i < count($keys) - 1; $i++){
    $arr1[$keys[$i]] = $arr1[$keys[$i+1]];
}
unset($arr1[$keys[count($keys) - 1]]);
print_r($arr1);
```

Comment: i have update the code and the logic please reread it

Comment: With your updated logic, you just have another associated array as the value of your associated array, so my code will work just fine.

Comment: Also, since all of your values are of the structure: 
["user_id => someValue ] 
You can directly replace value of a key of the main associative array with the value of the next key of the main associative array.
Instead of referring to the nested associative array since it will be a computationally expensive process.

Comment: thank man, its work ill try to learn more about  is there any definition about your can that make me understand more ? can you describe more by user_id ?

already try it ```$getDataFirebase['user_list'][$keys[$i]]['user_id'] = $getDataFirebase['user_list'][$keys[$i + 1]]['user_id'];```

like that ? @Varad Karpe

Comment: Yeah, that looks good to me, is it working for you though, since I did not try to check it by executing it.
What I was suggesting was this though  : 
$getDataFirebase['user_list'][$keys[$i]] = $getDataFirebase['user_list'][$keys[$i + 1]];
You do not need to refer to the ['user_id'] key if you do not plan on adding other attributes to every user in the future,but if you do want to do something like this : 
['user_id' => 1234, 'user_name' => 'user.name']
Then it becomes necessary to do it the way you have done it.

Answer (score -1):

i already solve the problem i found a simple way than @Varad Karpe, the answer is work but its need a lot of understanding if you new with it here is my code

```
            $_key = 1;

            $dataTemp = array();

            foreach ($getDataFirebase['user_list'] as $key => $value) {

                if ($params['user_id'] == $value['user_id']) {
                    unset($getDataFirebase['user_list'][$key]);
                }

                if ($params['user_id'] != $value['user_id']) {
                    $dataTemp['user_' . $_key] = $value;
                    $_key++;
                }
            }
```

the issue i have is change the key of $getDataFirebase['user_list'] to a new one and organize it so only the key change i make a new variable to store new structure data of user_list and its done